# How to deal with django migration under fab deploy that uses run() function

Tags: python, django, fabric

I have the following `fabfile.py` which I used for migrating development
Django code to production.

```
#--------------------------------------------------
# This script enable separation of development and production.
#--------------------------------------------------
from fabric.api import run, local, env, put, sudo
from fabric.contrib.project import rsync_project

env.hosts = ["bosswebserver"]
env.static_path = "/u33/app/www/coolapp/html/coolapp/"
env.app_path = "/u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/"





def collect_static():
    local('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=webframework.settings.dev')

def deploy_static():
    rsync_project(local_dir='.static/.',
                  remote_dir=env.static_path,
                  delete=True,
                  extra_opts='--no-perms --no-times')

def deploy_app():
    rsync_project(local_dir='.',
                  remote_dir=env.app_path,
                  delete=True,
                  exclude=['.static', 'user_files'],
                  extra_opts='--no-perms --no-times')

def migrate_db():
    run('python {app_path}manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod'.format(**env))

def restart_server():
    run('sudo /usr/local/bin/httpd_restart')

def deploy():
    collect_static()

    deploy_static()
    deploy_app()
    migrate_db()  # break here

    restart_server()
```

Now when I do

```
$ fab deploy
```

I get this message at the end:

```
webframework/settings/dev.py
webframework/settings/prod.py

sent 15.59K bytes  received 160.09K bytes  117.12K bytes/sec
total size is 25.46M  speedup is 144.92
[ bosswebserver] run: python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code -1 while executing!

Requested: python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod"

Aborting.
Disconnecting from bosswebserver... done.
```

How can I resolve the issue?

**Update**:

I tried this, it worked, by adding `r` in front:

```
def migrate_db():
    run(r'python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod')
```

However I'm still perplexed why this failed:

```
def migrate_db():
    run('python {app_path}manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod'.format(**env))
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command causing the issue by hand to see which is the output?

Comment: @Caumons: I tried plain command, not wrapped by `run()`. No error.

Comment: Try using `with` statement to change directory instead of placing the absolute path to `manage.py`

Comment: So, you've executed `python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod` with no error? Are you using the same user with right permissions when running by hand and running the fabfile?

Comment: ^ this is the main question here... Login with whatever user you're using and from `cd ~` run `python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod` does it work? Django inside global site-packages? Are you using virtualenv? There are about 5 questions to be answered here... My guess is that you forgot to path the settings file: `webframework.settings.prod` is NOT inside `~` which is what all indication points to...

Comment: I would add a with `cd(env.app_path): run('python manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod')` to `migrate_db()` .. but until i know more i cant say for sure.. either way, its a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Caumons: Correct, no error. I use same right permission.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi 1). It works. 2) Django under `~/.anaconda2/` (home). 3) No virtualenv. How do I add `webframework.settings.prod` to `~` ?

Comment: @Caumons and JavierBuzzi: See my update.

Comment: I personally don't bother `activat[e]`ing my environments anymore, i just reference them (absolute paths to the binary) and save myself a whole lot of headaches. (this applies to `pip` too)

Comment: You're ssh'ing as the SAME user and it works...? That makes 0 sense. But i'm willing to bet that if you ssh and say `which python` it will point to the anaconda path and through fabric: `which python` will point to the system python. So hack: `cd(env.app_path): run('/home/<user>/.anaconda/<env??>/bin/python /u33/app/www/coolapp/wsgi-scripts/coolapp/manage.py migrate --settings=webframework.settings.prod')` (just find the `python` executible). ALWAYS be explicit in your paths. Use `with cd(...):` basically everywhere helps readability and helps you making sense of everything

Comment: If using a raw string `r'mystring'` it works, then it looks like you have some spaces in your path names. This would be causing a confict when scaping them with `\ `. Is it the case? If that's true, try removing the spaces (saves lots of headaches) and try again with and without the raw string and both versions should work.

Comment: @Caumons -- what are you talking about? There are no spaces.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi, neversaint says that it works using raw strings, but it doesn't when using strings. So, I just told him to check if using spaces in his real paths because this could be an issue.